# How to INSERT the results of OUTPUT to the same table in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table called `ItemTable`, which has the columns:

```
ID (identity col int), primary key, foreign key constraint with ProductTable

Col (varchar(50))

ColOther (varchar(50))

Latest (bit)

Time (autogenerated datetime)
```

I'm doing a query:

```
UPDATE ItemTable
SET Col = 'new', ColOther = 'newother'
OUTPUT deleted.Col, deleted.ColOther
WHERE ID = 100;
```

Which updates the row just fine and gives the correct output:

```
| Col       | ColOther |
| --------- |:--------:|
| old       | oldother |
```

**I would like to `INSERT` this output (and the constant `Latest = 0`) to the same `ItemTable` in the same `UPDATE` statement.**

I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO ItemTable (Col, ColOther, Latest)
UPDATE ItemTable
SET Col = 'new', ColOther = 'newother'
OUTPUT deleted.Col, deleted.ColOther, 0
WHERE ID = 100;
```

Which gives the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'.

And:

```
UPDATE ItemTable
SET Col = 'new', ColOther = 'newother'
OUTPUT deleted.Col, deleted.ColOther, 0 INTO ItemTable
WHERE ID = 100;
```

Which gives the error:

> The target table 'ItemTable' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on
>   either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found
>   reference constraint 'FK_ProductTable_ItemTable'.

Comment: Why are you doing an `update` if you want to re-insert the values?  Just do an `insert` the first time.  And what is the function of `id` if it can be duplicated?

Comment: This has all the indications of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to change one of the column values (`Latest`) to an other value, on the newly inserted row,

Comment: @SeanLange Possibly, but I'm sure this can be accomplished anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in a single statement.
You have to use one statement for update and one for insert.
However, you can do it in a transaction, so that if the insert fails you can rollback the update:

```
DECLARE @updated TABLE (Col varchar(50), ColOther varchar(50))

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

UPDATE ItemTable
SET Col = 'new', ColOther = 'newother'
OUTPUT deleted.Col, deleted.ColOther INTO @updated
WHERE ID = 100

INSERT INTO ItemTable (Col, ColOther, Latest)
SELECT Col, ColOther, 0
FROM @updated

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution! Please don't mind my edit, I just set the `Latest` to be a constant 0, added the datatypes and formatted this a bit.

Comment: Glad to help :-)